# How to set Rpi 3 camera exposure time and ISO in opencv C++ code?

Tags: pi-3b+

I wanted to know how to set the value for ISO and exposure time in c++ for image capture using opencv.

I tried using the following code to set manual mode but did not work.

```
capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_AUTO_EXPOSURE,0.25);

capture.set(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,100);
```

I got the following error:

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: Property <unknown property string>(21) not supported by device

HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: Property Exposure(15) not supported by device
```

Comment: The you say it did not work - did you get an error message?  If so, can you edit the questions and show it.